Chinese movie series name where mc is creator and smart but he lost h's memory
The reason I remember clearly about this series is that in one epsoide he made a prosthetic arm and leg with iron for a bandit out of pity but that bandit/robber used it to rob bank or pawn shop (cuz it was set in ancient historical era). Mc was also smart and intelligent creator/innovator. But he cant use martial arts.
